# Firebase push notifications on Android with multiple modules

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I'm currently trying to implement push notifications in our application.

So we have three modules.

- App 1
- Logic
- App 2

I gave them obviously names. App 1 and 2 have a dependency on the logic module. This module contains ALL the logic for both apps. Now I want App specific notifications to users that are logged in on App 1 OR App 2.

Problem:

I can't put the firebase logic into the Logic module since this module is configured as a lib module and isn't configured as an App. Now I have to put the firebase logic in App 1 and 2, but I can't access this logic from the Logic module since App 1 and 2 have a dependency on the Logic module and not the other way around.

Firebase requires a google-services.json for every app connected, this file is required to generate a user specific pushtoken.

Is there a way to configure this so that I can generate user specific tokens for push notifications? So after a user logs in a pushtoken has to be generated according to the App and user so this user can get a notifcation on said device which he/she is logged in.

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: sorry, it's not clear enough, what is app 1 and app 2? two separated applications?

Comment: Two separated applications who use the logic from the module Logic. But in the Logic module there are certain behaviors that are different for each App.

Comment: you can't do that this way, firebase does not require google-services.json, but google play services itself (lib), you need to do that manually

Comment: But don't the firebase dependencies require the google play services lib? Or can I just compile the firebase dependency in the Logic module?

Comment: exactly, firebase lib need google play services plugin, that's why you need to do it manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be nothing stopping you from implementing what you're describing.

You can still add Firebase SDK dependencies to a library module.  You just can't use the google-services plugin on it - that belongs only on application modules.

Comment: Ahh yes, i've tried this and it works indeed. Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem where I added the firebase sdk to my library module and applied the plugin to the app module.  But its giving me a collision saying : `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has different version for the compile (9.0.0) and runtime (11.4.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution`  Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: @Naveed did you found an answer for your question? I've some trouble with the same scenario.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of play services.  That was the problem I was having.  Check your top level gradle to ensure play services version:  `com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1`

Comment: I am facing the same issue and not sure how to fix this. Can you please share the steps to fix this issue?

Comment: Guys whats is the solution exactly?

Answer (score 0):

A more updated answer: You CAN create a module of Firebase Cloud Notifications separated from an app client
To make it work you have to:

On Module (Library):

- Add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'` in module gradle file
- Add

  `<service android:name=".firebase.YourNotificationService">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
       </intent-filter>
   </service>`

in the Android Manifest file.

On your app client:

- Add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` on the last line in your module gradle file
- Add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'` in your module gradle file
- Add `implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'` in your module gradle file
- Add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` inside "dependencies" block of your project gradle file
- Add your "google-services.json" file inside your "app" folder

And that's it. That will work.